# Getting started with Power Dissipation Problem

Tags: power, resistance, power-dissipation

I'm studying my first semester of EE. We're only a few weeks through and I am stuck on a simple homework problem.
The details are:
Seven components are given. They include two voltage sources (4V
and 8V), two current sources (5A and 10A) and three resistors (3Ω, 6Ω and 9Ω). 
The sources can produce a maximum of 500W. All elements have a maximum dissipation
rating of 1kW.

Each source can be re-used but not within the same circuit.
Each circuit can only use a maximum of 3 components

The fist question is
**Design a circuit that will dissipate 80w from any voltage source.**

My approach was to start with the 4v source and calculate the resistance required to dissipate 80w.

p = i<sup>2</sup>R

80w = 4v<sup>2</sup>*R

R=0.2Ω


Looking at the available parts I can't make 0.2Ω resistance.

In parallel I get:
3&6 = 1/((1/3)+(1/6)) = 2Ω
3&9 = 2.25Ω
6&9 = 3.6Ω

I'm obviously missing something with this question.

---

After some helpful replies I've realised that the current sources will provide 'any voltage' as stated in the question while maintaining a constant current for the circuit to dissipate the required 80w however I still can't get the numbers to agree.

If choosing the 5A supply I get:

80w = 5i<sup>2</sup>*R

80w/25i = R
R<sub>req.</sub> = 3.2Ω

If choosing the 10A supply I get:

80w = 10i<sup>2</sup>*R

80w/100i = R
R<sub>req.</sub> = 0.8Ω

From above I can't make this work using 2 resistors (only allowed 3 elements from the list).

Comment: You could do the same with the 8 V source and you will probably end up with the same, a solution cannot be found. But what if you used a current source ? The *from any voltage source* implies a trick, with the available components you **cannot** build something which will always dissipate 80 W for any given voltage, **assuming the power comes from that voltage source.** But what if the power was coming from something else ?

Comment: Ah, I see the trick now. A current source will provide 'any voltage' and maintain current thus allowing power dissipation to remain constant for a single circuit. I'll do some more work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, the question does not impose to use resistors only, therefore I think the simplest approach would be to connect a `10A` current source with an `8volts` voltage source. Since `P=VI`, your circuit ends up dissipating `80watts`.

[image]

Comment: Providing the answer directly does not help the OP in understand how to solve problems of this type...

Comment: Not bad, although I don't see how this meets the "from any source" condition.

Comment: @PhilFrost is there another solution to the problem that can dissipate 80watts. I just couldn't do it with the available resistors?

Comment: @PhilFrost, I assumed ""from any voltage source" means "You are free to choose 4v or 8v voltage source". If it is not so, it requires a circuit that automatically adjusts its current, i.e when 4v is used its current must be 20A and when 8v source is used its current must be 10A which I do not think with only 3 components is feasible.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \begin{align}
 P &= IE \\
   &= I^2 R \\
   &= E^2 / R
\end{align}$$

Since you have at your disposal a selection of current and voltage sources, you have a means to hold \$I\$ or \$E\$ constant. And you have resistors available, so you can control \$R\$ also. So as a start, look for combinations of sources and resistors that result in the desired power according to the last two of these equations.

I'll also give you another hint: if the question specifies "from a *voltage* source", you'll probably want to use a *current* source in your solution.